# how to convert a key value array to an object for embedding in a FireStore array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, google-cloud-firestore, key-value

My program builds the following data by the user making any number of selections from lists on the screen.

```
[4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea", p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml", ....]
```

and I need to convert it to key:value object for storing as an embedded object in a FireStore document. I have found some solutions to a similar problem where the array format is

```
[4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea"]   [p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml"]
```

and have even tried to alter one and failed. If anyone is able to help me or  point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

I need the data to be converted to an object

```
{4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea", p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml"}
```

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: I have some data in the following format                 [4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea", p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce"]  but I need to convert it to                                              
{4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea"} {p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce"}

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like so:

```
var data = new Map();
data.set("4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710", "Tea");
data.set("p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU", "soy sauce 30ml");
```

### MDN says:

> The **`Map`** object holds key-value pairs. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

**IMPORTANT!**
The syntax of your arrays is not valid in JavaScript.

```
[4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea",   p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml", ...]
[4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea"]   [p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml"]
```

JavaScript arrays do not hold key-value pairs. Objects do.

```
var myObj = {
  "4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710": "Tea",
  "p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU": "soy sauce 30ml"
};
```

The syntax of arrays is:

```
var myArr = [item1, item2, item3, ..., itemN];
```

Learn more about [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

---

**EDIT**

If you want absolutely to generate an array and then convert it to an object, you can do this:

```js
var data = [
  ["4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710", "Tea"],
  ["p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU", "soy sauce 30ml"]
];

var converted = toObject(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(converted));

function toObject(dataArr) {
  var obj = {};
  dataArr.forEach(([key, value]) => obj[key] = value);
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I do not understand how to do it. I have googled Map but I am unable to relate it to the code you supplied.

Comment: I've put a link right in the first line for that.  Where I say: " `Use a JavaScript Map`".

Comment: I just saw the edit of your question. You can't convert the initial array because it is not even an array. The syntax is not correct. That should be itself an object instead. See the links I provided in my edit. Here are the 3 links: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: I googled that and other pages and could not see how I can use  Map to  convert the data to an object.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help. I guess I will have to rewrite the code that generates the data.

Comment: If you want an object, you can simply make your program produce objects. it is simpler. It is just that maps are levels above objects in terms of key-value pairs. But objects still works.

Comment: If you still want to begin with arrays, it has to be nested arrays like: `[[key, value], [key, value]]`

Answer (score 0):

It's works 
This code convert array to object in js

```js
var objectResult = {};
var arr = ['4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710', 'Tea', 'p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU', 'soy sauce 30ml']

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
   if (i%2 === 0) {
      objectResult[ arr[i] ] =  arr[i+1]
   }

}

console.log(objectResult);

/*
Result: 

{
   4CsIFrIQDV7tnoWVi710: "Tea",
   p3hycHeNi2sa8PTOuxjU: "soy sauce 30ml"
}

*/
```